# system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 58 - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to run my project on `admin` directory.
my directory:

```
public_html //installed wordpress
   /admin
```

on my localhost everything works fine but on my server I got this error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in /home/saanapp/public_html/admin/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 58
```

my `config` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://saanapp.com/admin/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

permission of `admin` directory is `755`.

my `codeigniter` version is:

```
const CI_VERSION = '3.1.5';
```

my php verson is:

```
PHP Version 5.2.17
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the version of PHP you are using. [Server requirements](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html) for CodeIgniter state:

> PHP version 5.6 or newer is recommended.

Line 58 of CodeIgniter.php uses the PHP keyword `const` which was not added to PHP until version 5.3.0 ([PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/const)).

Seems possible that your development server is using a newer version of PHP than the one referenced in your question which is why it worked there but does not on the live server.